# Error getting file: -6: Not Supported [Ubuntu 14.04 & LG G3]

Tags: 14.04, android, lg

I'm trying to transfer a folder of files from my LG G3 to my laptop and each attempt has lead me to this error:

[image]

I've just unlocked the LG G3's bootloader using BUMP! and I made a backup within TWRP Recovery. Now I just want to keep a copy of the backup on my laptop, but it will not transfer over.

Answer (score 0):

There are rules to naming files. A - is an illegal character at the front of a file name since it indicates that the next part of what is typed is an -option- to the command used. Example with touch (but also applies to cp or mv and other commands):

```
$ touch -1
$ touch: invalid option -- '1'
$ Try 'touch --help' for more information.
```

This works (the -- informs the system that there are no options but the - is part of the filename:)

```
$ touch -- -1
$
```

If you use different file system it is adviced to use a file name convention that is supported by both filesystems.

So analyzing your notice I would say that you should rename the file named `-6` since the system assumes it is an option named `-6` that is not part of the command used (ie. "not supported" as stated in the notice).

---

By the way: you should consider this a -bug- and report it to the maintainer of the software used. In my opinion that software should take care of this by using above method to end the instructions options to copy the files over to another system (in the same fashion a space will break the command if not taken into account since a space is considered the end of a filename and the start of a second filename if the filename is not surrounded by double-quotes).

Comment: But none of the files begin with a "-" Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ZNJ8xnH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my HTC One M8 and solved it using a solution provided here: [Stack Overflow: Unable to mount SAMSUNG_Android in UBUNTU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055304/unable-to-mount-samsung-android-in-ubuntu)
Thanks to [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2492784/sven)

Attention: It could be, that you need to enable the "usb debugging", to see the device by "lsub". This can be done like this:

Android 2.3 - Gingerbread: Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging

Android 4.0 - Ice Cream Sandwich: Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging

Android 4.1 - Jelly Bean: Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging

Android 4.2 or higher - Jelly Bean:

- Settings > About
- scroll to Build number and tap it 7 times
- now you will find "Developer Options" in the "Settings"-menu
- go to it and enable "USB Debugging"

The next steps helped me to automount my device on Linux Mint with an already installed "gfvs":

Find the vendorid and productid with lsub:

```
$> lsusb
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0bb4:0c02 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo (Debug)
...
```

the "0bb4" is the vendor-id, the "0c02"is the productid

open the file "/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules" for edit:

```
$> gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
```

Insert the new device, by duplicating a previous one and correcting the id's and save the file:

```
# Wiko DARKMOON
ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c02", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Unplug your smartphone and replug it. Your Linux should mount your device like it would do for other one.